# How do I test if a Java RMI object is alive?

Tags: java, rmi

How can I test if my reference to an remote object is still alive?

Answer (score 1):

Call any method on the object. A RemoteException will be thrown if the object is not alive.

Comment: Would calling hashCode() trigger a RuntimeException?

Comment: Call any remote method on the object. That will tell you if it is reachable.

Comment: No. A NoSuchObjectException will be thrown if the object is not alive, and that's not a RuntimeException, it's a RemoteException.